# Какая асимптотика О большое будет у этого кода

Tags: асимптотика

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8     };
   std::vector<int> v2{        5,  7,  9,10};
   std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end());
   std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end());

   std::vector<int> v_symDifference;

   std::set_symmetric_difference(
       v1.begin(), v1.end(),
       v2.begin(), v2.end(),
       std::back_inserter(v_symDifference));

   for(int n : v_symDifference)
       std::cout << n << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Свои мысли-то есть?

Comment: Добавьте в код комментарии со сложностями всех операторов. Если вы ошибётесь, мы поможем.